# Removing Purchase Note from admin email woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have direct modified the `abstract-wc-order.php` in the `includes` folder (of my child theme) to remove the `purchase_note`from the admin emails.

```
'items'               => $this->get_items(),
        'show_download_links' => $this->is_download_permitted() && ! $args['sent_to_admin'],
        'show_sku'            => $args['show_sku'],
        'show_purchase_note'  => $this->is_paid() && ! $args['sent_to_admin'],
        'show_image'          => $args['show_image'],
        'image_size'          => $args['image_size'],
        'sent_to_admin'       => $args['sent_to_admin']
```

But it isn't working. Is there a way to override this file from my theme folder? 
Any suggestions?

Comment: why would you want to remove the `purchase_note`?

Comment: I want to remove the purchase note on the admin new order email only.In our store, the purchase notes advise the client how to use the product. Admins do not need to see these notes. It makes the emails very long. Admins do not need to see the subtotal, payment method or shipping (in our store) either because its info they already know. They just need a more streamline email with the basics, product, client email and shipping info.

Comment: I have never thought about that... nice point...

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer at least for the purchase note:

Here's how you can remove the `purchase note` from the Admin New Order email.

https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/commit/657521ffa445cd25d0ae0d7759f7ae4c92b7a87c

According to the developer, Version 2.5.2 will be added to the master files.